# How to exit a supervisor process with fabric file?

Tags: python, fabric, supervisord

I'm using fabric to connect to a remote host. In which I called supervisor to see the status. But I don't know how to use fabric file to exit the supervisor interface. How to do it?

My fabfile is like this:

```
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.api import env

env.hosts = [
    'my_host'
    ]

def my_fab():
    run("supervisorctl -u 'me' -p 'aaa'")

>>> fab my_fab
>>> # plenty of stdout 
>>> supervisor>                             # I'm stuckled here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather about using `supervisorctl` than using `fabric`

## Avoid fab calls to commands, requiring user interaction

Fabric does one-shot calls to commands and then returns. Shall be no long term activity on console. The solution for your problem is not to enter interactive mode (which awaits some further input), but call `supervisor` only in non-interactive mode.

## Calling `supervisorctl` in non-interactive mode

Supervisor control command provides interactive and non-interactive mode.

You non-interacive mode.

E.g. in my installation, I have a service called `logproxy`

Calling `supervisorctl` in this way:

```
$ supervisorctl status logproxy
logproxy                         STOPPED    Not started
```

Applying this to your fab task shall make it working.

Following the sample code from "Welcome to Fabric!" it would look like:

```
from fabric.api import run

def super_status():
    uname = "zen"
    pswd = "then"
    cmd = "supervisorctl -u {uname} -p {pswd} status logproxy".format(uname=uname, pswd=pswd)
    # to see the command you are going to call, just for show
    print cmd
    # and run it
    run(cmd)
```

And would be used.

```
$ fab -l
```

to list it.

and calling the task `super_status`:

```
$ fab super_status -H localhost
```

Comment: should I add in your code my username and password? I guess it's yes?

Comment: Should I write" run("supervisorctl -u 'me' -p 'aaa' stauts logproxy
logproxy  STOPPED  Not started") in my fabfile?

Comment: And I think this question can also converted to "how to type in texts with fabric in a prompt line?"

Comment: Your call to supervisorctl shall only call `supervisorctl status logproxy`, optionally with `-p` and `-u` options. You shall first get proper results on command line with `supervisorctl` and then call it by `fab`.

Comment: I think there could be a easier way, which fabric will allow me to input in supervisor, all it is said that fabric lose it's power after I entered the supervisor interface?

Comment: @Zen The point is, that `fabric` will loose the power at the moment, you enter interactive mode of commands you call. So if you can, you shall avoid using interactive mode. You may try using commands in interactive mode, but for your task this is not needed at all.

Comment: Is there a simple way to enter non-interactive mode in fabric?

Comment: I saw it over and over. Actually what I need is quit the supervisor process, no matter If I need to invoke a another Linux command or not. The only command I know to stop a process is ctrl + Z. Should I write a parallel fabric function like run('^Z')?

Comment: besides, I didn't saw the difference between my code and the example, I just set the hostname inside my fabfile.

Comment: @Zen You shall not enter interactive mode at all, try to avoid that and you are done.

Comment: I execute your newly edited code, but it says  ***Unknown syntax:statuscmd. And I commented this statuscmd out. And that supervisor> comes out again...

Comment: @Zen - you shall work through fabric tutorial first, here I cannot teach you basics of it. Sorry.

Comment: Wow, I changed that statuscmd into status, and everything works now! Amazing!

Comment: Vlcinksy , Things works now, the fabric document is really an ocean. I've been researching it for 4 hours. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @Zen sorry, this was my mistake, which I corrected later on. Good luck.